# LUKS partition still accessible after removing drive physically

Tags: encryption, luks

I have a USB flash drive with Full Disk Encryption using LUKS.
I plugged in the drive and mounted it as such using the following:

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb flash
mount /dev/mapper/flash /mnt/flash
```

If I physically remove my flash drive I can still access it's contents at /mnt/flash. Why is this? I see it as a security risk as I want my flash drive contents to become inaccessible as soon as the drive is physically removed.

What can I do to make this happen? It needs to be something I can do to the drive as I use this on other computers and I don't want to have to change them all to make the drive secure.

Comment: Could be just a few cached files & entries. How much data can you actually read/copy? After flushing the disk caches can you still read anything? ps. you'll probably corrupt the filesystem if it was mounted `rw` by yanking it out

Comment: Well my SSH private key is on there, and I can still use it to authenticate via SSH to other machines. Desirable behavior would be that if it was removed the key would not remain usable in RAM.

Comment: Interestingly, I think the data may remain in ram even after cleanly unmounting & luksClose & removing it, it just might be marked as "free", not unlike deleting a file. But unmounting first sounds like your answer, even a quick alias or desktop shortcut or something to click. Or, write a program/script that looks for the device every so often, and tries to umount it if it's missing. Or, switch off all the power after pulling out the usb (or before, wouldn't matter) would ensure nothing's easily accessible.

Comment: "Or, write a program/script that looks for the device every so often, and tries to umount it if it's missing. " That seems like a great solution, actually, Thanks!

Comment: If I knew exactly what to look for, I'd have put it in an answer. Actually I did just look up how to know what device any file is on, so maybe I could think up something...

Comment: Yeah much appreciated. That being said, I wish the device would just be inaccessible once it was removed from the computer. It defeats the purpose of having sensitive information on the flash drive if I have to make sure to unmount otherwise it's contents will remain accessible anytime it's removed. And scripting to fix that, while an option, would mean I have to use said script on every computer I use the drive on.

Comment: No problem (fyi an upvote is a recommended "thanks", even a check-mark if it answers the Q best ;-) It looks like that's just the way the system works. There are programs that run in a panel or "notification area" to click eject drives too, and most file managers show an eject button

Comment: Sorry, I thought I gave you a +1, I just did now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ran a program / script from the USB itself, you should be able to figure out what LUKS map/name and device it's on (or just tell the script the device or mapped name if you know it) and watch for when the device "disappears" when it's removed. Then unmount it.

I'm *pretty sure* that unplugging a USB will cause the device (`/dev/sdXn`) to disappear, but in case it doesn't you'd have to watch `dmesg` or look in the syslog, or find it somewhere in `/sys` perhaps.

Here's a proof-of-concept bash script that looks like it should work, but I don't have any LUKS partitions on usb's to test with, so **I'm not sure if `umount` might need options like `--lazy` or `--force`.**

```
map=$( df --output=source $PWD |tail -n1 )

device=$( sudo cryptsetup status "$map" | grep -o "device:.*"|cut -d' ' -f 3 )

while [ -b "$device" ]
do
    sleep 30
done

echo "Device $device is missing, unmounting"
sudo umount -v "$map"
```

If it's run from inside the mounted LUKS container, `$PWD` should find the LUKS name it's mapped on, and then the device, and if the device stops being a block special file then unmount the mapped device.

PS If the device was mounted rw (writeable) the filesystem can be corrupted by suddenly unplugging it. FAT seems especially vulnerable, while a journaling filesystem should be more robust. If it's mounted ro (read-only) at least you could avoid that problem, mount accepts `-o ro` and cryptsetup accepts `--readonly` (both probably aren't necessary)

Comment: I've tried this but umount.crypt just core-dumps. I'm using ubuntu 22.04. What's the alternative?

Comment: I'm not sure, even with the --lazy or --force options? Core dumps are usually bugs... Could try to close the device with cryptsetup, perhaps with it's --deferred option. Or call dmsetup's remove or clear or wipe_table commands?

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer (I only got to know now). The lazy option works but then I cannot reconnect. With `--force` it core-dumps. I'll try those other options next time it happened (I ended up rebooting). I didn't know they existed. Thank you very much.

Comment: ($PWD is /dev/mapper) dmsetup remove -f  _dev_sda causes log: `Buffer I/O error on dev dm-6, logical block 2468362112, async page read`. `dmsetup remove -f` is successful, `dmsetup clear -f` is successful, `dmsetup wipe_table -f` is successful but then `dmsetup remove -f` still doesn't work.

Comment: I'd imagine unplugging a drive without syncing and umounting would lead to at least a few errors, no matter what, including I/O errors, and possibly corrupt the drive's filesystem. The best would still be doing a "quick umount", maybe through a script, keyboard shortcut, or a "click here to run" program. (PS. if the answer has been even a little useful, do toss an upvote my way ;-)

Comment: I'm not unplugging the drive, though. It's just disconnecting for less than 1s. It might be some tinny energy failure on the USB hub. I wish I could just know before that and stop it... I'm working on alternatives, including a different version of `unmount.crypt`. When I want ti unplug, I use `unmount` and `cryptsetup close`. Thank you for the help so far

Comment: Ah, usb can be temperamental, fixing that bug would be best. I keep a usb drive always connected and it hasn't "flickered out" before, although when I used FAT it would get corrupted regularly, no problems with ext, but yours sounds like a hardware issue. Definitely try the usual: new cords & hub, different port, etc. Maybe even a newer/older kernel? I'm not sure how much further to go with the disconnect-detecting script, I spotted a hdparm option "-w device  reset (DANGEROUS)" that might work for a hard drive-like drive, maybe not a thumb drive. But maybe upvote if something's been helpful?

Comment: Thanks. For now, I updated to kernel 6.1.0 and I'll see what happens.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be skipping some steps in the process.  You should:

- Insert the drive
- `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb flash`
- `mount /dev/mapper/flash /mnt/flash`
- Use the drive as normal
- `umount /mnt/flash`
- `cryptsetup close flash`
- Remove the drive

The inverse of `mount` is `umount`.  Trying to `umount` a non-inserted drive may hang, depending on what the system is trying to do.  The `cryptsetup close` step further removes the drive's mapping and wipes the encryption key from kernel memory.

You cannot guarantee that all (meta-)data is properly written to the device if you physically remove it without calling `umount`.  Your encryption key is still available in memory until you call `cryptsetup close`.  With that in mind, these steps should not be skipped.

Comment: Right. I understand that it *shouldn't* be removed without properly closing and unmounting. But in this scenario is there a failsafe I can use to ensure that the drive automatically unmounts or cryptsetup closes the drive upon the drive physically being removed? I have my SSH key on here and I don't want it accessible after I remove the drive if I don't unmount properly.

Comment: @Patrick After removing a drive, you can try a `umount -f` to force an unmount (but this has a chance to hang), or `umount -l` to at least make the files inaccessible until a real unmount can occur.

Comment: That'll have to do. I was hoping there was an automated way...

Comment: How could a savagely unplugged drive be unmounted auto[mg]atically after the fact? Even Windows can't do it (hence the tray icon)! If you're using a GUI, you can umount the drive from a file manager like Nautilus before unplugging the drive, way easier than using the command line, you can also mount your drive from a file manager.

Comment: @cylgalad My comment was only meant to imply "make the file tree inaccessible" rather than a true unmount

Comment: @cylgalad Less concerned with actually unmounting, more concerned with "the device isn't there - from a security perspective, we don't want the contents to stay in memory". I understand the concept that it can't be unmounted automatically, but I would expect the exact opposite behavior of what I'm seeing (and desire it as well). Something like an I/O error when accessing contents of a removed drive. That would be preferable.